# NullPointerException in GenericFilterBean on Spring Boot application start after adding a custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

NullPointerException in GenericFilterBean on Spring Boot application start after adding a custom filter that extends OncePerRequestFilter.

Here is the stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.apache.commons.logging.Log.isDebugEnabled()" because
> "this.logger" is null
> at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:241)

We are using Spring Boot version 2.7.6.

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Let me guess, using AOP with some catch all pointcut, proxying the filter.

Comment: Yes, we have this one: 

 @Around("execution(* com.app.services.register..*.* (..))")
 public Object logOnStartAndBeforeReturnOfMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

Comment: @M.Deinum would you share more on this, whether it is causing the issue?

Comment: It is. As it proxies the filter, the `init` method is `final` cannot be proxied, will thus be executed on the proxy instead of being passed through to the actual object. The proxy doesn't have any of its fields initialized (no need to) and thus here you get a `NullPointerException`. Don't mnake your pointcut so broad (or exclude the filter package for instance).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Spring Boot app and **Micrometer**. I realized that **you cannot use Micrometer annotations whenever you want**. It happens because of the Proxy mechanism. **JDK Dynamic Proxy** can only create proxy if the target class implements at least 1 interface whereas **CGLIB Proxy** has no such limitation and is able to create proxy as long as the target class / method is non-final. This is important because it will help us understand why **Spring AOP will not work on OncePerRequestFilter class**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I have restricted the filter package to just controllers as suggested by Deimun, and it started working.

Comment: how do you restrict the filter to controller?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exception with an OncePerRequestFilter. The following solution fixed the Problem:

```
  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter> applicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter(){
    ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter filter =  new ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean<ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
    registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1);
    return registration;
  }
```